# The action 'create' & 'destroy' could not be found for RelationshipsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im in the last chapter of Ruby on Rails tutorial by M.Hartl and I'm facing the problem with actions 'create' and 'destroy'

I already checked title of my all files. I receive errors during tests:

```
ERROR["test_should_unfollow_a_user_with_Ajax", FollowingTest, 2015-12-03 23:12:38 +0000]  test_should_unfollow_a_user_with_Ajax#FollowingTest (1449184358.75s) AbstractController::ActionNotFound:         AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action 'destroy' could not be found for RelationshipsController
            test/integration/following_test.rb:53:in `block (2 levels) in <class:FollowingTest>'
            test/integration/following_test.rb:52:in `block in <class:FollowingTest>'
        test/integration/following_test.rb:53:in `block (2 levels) in <class:FollowingTest>'
        test/integration/following_test.rb:52:in `block in <class:FollowingTest>'
```

The same error is for create action.

relationships_controller.rb

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root                'static_pages#home'
  get    'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get    'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get    'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get    'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :microposts,          only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships,       only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

following_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class FollowingTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user  = users(:michael)
    @other = users(:archer)
    log_in_as(@user)
  end

  test "following page" do
    get following_user_path(@user)
    assert_not @user.following.empty?
    assert_match @user.following.count.to_s, response.body
    @user.following.each do |user|
      assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(user)
    end
  end

  test "followers page" do
    get followers_user_path(@user)
    assert_not @user.followers.empty?
    assert_match @user.followers.count.to_s, response.body
    @user.followers.each do |user|
      assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(user)
    end
  end

  test "should follow a user the standard way" do
    assert_difference '@user.following.count', 1 do
      post relationships_path, followed_id: @other.id
    end
  end

  test "should follow a user with Ajax" do
    assert_difference '@user.following.count', 1 do
      xhr :post, relationships_path, followed_id: @other.id
    end
  end

  test "should unfollow a user the standard way" do
    @user.follow(@other)
    relationship = @user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @other.id)
    assert_difference '@user.following.count', -1 do
      delete relationship_path(relationship)
    end
  end

  test "should unfollow a user with Ajax" do
    @user.follow(@other)
    relationship = @user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @other.id)
    assert_difference '@user.following.count', -1 do
      xhr :delete, relationship_path(relationship)
    end
  end
end
```

Does anyone have any idea what's the problem?  I checked other questions of this error and none of them are applicable to my application. 
Many thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Can you add following_test.rb to your question ?

Comment: Hello! following_test.rb has been added.